# keras "unknown loss function" error after defining custom loss function

Tags: keras

I defined a new loss function in keras in losses.py file. I close and relaunch anaconda prompt, but I got `ValueError: ('Unknown loss function', ':binary_crossentropy_2')`. I'm running keras using python2.7 and anaconda on windows 10.

I temporarily solve it by adding the loss function in the python file I compile my model.

Comment: Please provide some source code, you don't need to add your loss to losses.py in order for it to work.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro. I added it to losses.py because I want all models to be able to use it instead of defining it in the same file as the model. Thanks for the reminder, I will do that for now.

Answer (score 48):

In Keras we have to pass the custom functions in the `load_model` function:

```
def my_custom_func():
    # your code
    return
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('my_model.h5', custom_objects={'my_custom_func':                   
my_custom_func})
```

Answer (score 7):

None of these solutions worked for me because I had two or more nested functions for multiple output variables.

my solution was to not compile when loading the model. I compile the model later on with the list of loss functions that were used when you trained the model.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

# load model weights, but do not compile
model = load_model("mymodel.h5", compile=False)

# printing the model summary 
model.summary()

# custom loss defined for feature 1
def function_loss_o1(weights)
    N_c = len(weights)
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        output_loss = ... 
        return output_loss/N_c
    return loss

# custom loss defined for feature 2
def function_loss_o2(weights)
    N_c = len(weights)
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        output_loss = ... 
        return output_loss/N_c
    return loss 

# list of loss functions for each output feature
losses = [function_loss_o1, function_loss_o2]

# compile and train the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=losses, metrics=['accuracy'])

# now you can use compiled model to predict/evaluate, etc
eval_dict = {}
eval_dict["test_evaluate"] = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
```

Comment: This answer is correct when you have multiple outputs.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have luck with the above solutions, but I was able to do this:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects

get_custom_objects().update({'my_custom_func': my_custom_func})

model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

I found the solution here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5916#issuecomment-294373616

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to call the function via string alias, which requires more tampering with Keras' `losses.py` to map the string to the function (something you should not do as it gets overridden if you update the package). Instead just declare the function in your project and pass it to the `loss` parameter, for example:

```
from your.project import binary_crossentropy_2
# ...
model.fit(epochs, loss=binary_crossentropy_2)
```

As long as your function follows the satisfies the requirements [here](https://keras.io/losses/), it will work fine.

Comment: That seems to be the way to do it, but I can't import `from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy_2`  The error was: "Cannot import name binary_crossentrophy2"

Comment: Where did you define the function? Maybe try moving the declaration to the same file where you call `model.fit()`, so there's no need to import. If you have a package named `keras` in your project, that might be the problem since Python will look in your distribution libraries first.

Comment: It seems this "loss"  argument doesn't exist anymore in the model.fit function, I am using tensorflow 1.15.0

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the function to the losses.py in keras within the environment's folder. At first, I added it in `anaconda2/pkgs/keras.../losses.py`, so that's why I got the error.

The path for losses.py in the environment is something like:

`anaconda2/envs/envname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py`