# Keras custom loss error : Unknown loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I have tried to customize a loss function in Keras.

I have tried two approaches:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.losses import mean_absolute_error

def mae_in_minute(y_true, y_pred):
    temp = K.mean(K.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)/60
    return temp
```

and

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.losses import mean_absolute_error

def mae_in_minute(y_true, y_pred):
    return mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)/60
```

My model structure is:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=training.shape[1:len(training.shape)])
added = Conv2D(128, (3, training.shape[2]),activation="relu")(input_layer)
added = Flatten()(added)
added = Dense(600, activation='relu')(added)
added = Dense(400, activation='relu')(added)
added = Dense(256, activation='relu')(added)
added = Dense(256, activation='relu')(added)
added = Dense(256, activation='relu')(added)
added = Dense(200, activation='relu')(added)
added = Dense(100, activation='relu')(added)
added = Dense(50, activation='relu')(added)
output_temp = Dense(2,activation='softmax', name="temp_output")(added)
output_time = Dense(1,activation='relu', name="time_output")(added)
model = Model(input=input_layer, output=[output_temp,output_time])
losses = {
    "temp_output": "categorical_crossentropy",
    "time_output": "mae_in_minute",
}
lossWeights = {"temp_output": 1.0, "time_output": 1.0}
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=losses, loss_weights=lossWeights)
model.summary()
```

But I get this error message with both custom loss approaches:

> > Unknown loss function:mae_in_minute

How do I fix this problem?

I have found one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576576/keras-unknown-loss-function-error-after-defining-custom-loss-function).

But is this the only way to use a custom loss? To save my model in advance and load it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try removing the quotation?  `"time_output": mae_in_minute`

Comment: It works after removing the quotation ! Thanks a million

Comment: @KotaMori, can you put this as an answer, so Jim can accept it? That way people can know it has been answered?

Comment: That will be great.

Comment: can any one tell me how removing quotation solve this problem..

Comment: @JimChen Thanks for your consideration.  This time, can you accept your own answer?

Comment: @UmerFarooq Loss functions are supposed to be function.  Passing strings like "mse" is just a shortcut only for built-in loss functions for keras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the quoation of custom loss, and it should run perfectly.
#My_loss

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.losses import mean_absolute_error

def mae_in_minute(y_true, y_pred):
    return mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)/60
```

##Before
losses = {
"temp_output": "categorical_crossentropy",
"time_output": "mae_in_minute",
}
lossWeights = {"temp_output": 1.0, "time_output": 1.0}
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=losses, loss_weights=lossWeights)
model.summary()

##After
losses = {
"temp_output": "categorical_crossentropy",
"time_output": mae_in_minute,
}
lossWeights = {"temp_output": 1.0, "time_output": 1.0}
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=losses, loss_weights=lossWeights)
model.summary()